# Pattern printing problem in java: “frame" composed out of the symbols ‘.’ and ‘*’, dimensions AxB

Tags: java

Write a program that reads natural numbers a and b and prints a “frame” composed of the symbols ‘.’ and ‘*’ dimensions axb as below (dots are inside and stars around the dots):

```
a=4,b=4;  a=3,b=1
****     *
*..*     *
*..*     *
****
```

I solved it this way:

```
static void first(int a, int b) {
    for(int i=1; i<=a; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<=b;j++) {
            if (i==1 || i==a || j==1 || j==b)
                System.out.print("*");
            else System.out.print(".");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The next task is a bit different, here is what a program should return for given a and b:

```
a=3,b=1     
**** 
*..*
*..*
****
*..*
*..*
****
*..*
*..*
****


a=4,b=4
*************
*..*..*..*..*
*..*..*..*..*
*************
*..*..*..*..*
*..*..*..*..*
*************
*..*..*..*..*
*..*..*..*..*
*************
*..*..*..*..*
*..*..*..*..*
*************
```

I do not know how to do this one, when I tried using the first method as a help method I just get a messy pattern..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about it, a `*` is always used for the `3*i`th element in a row where `i` ranges from `0` to `a*3`. It's similar for the columns: it's always the `3*j`th element in a col where `j` ranges from `0` to `b*j`. All other elements are `.`s.

You can express this structure simply by using the modulo operation (`%`):

```java
class Main {
    
    static void print(int a, int b) {
        for (int row = 0; row <= a*3; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col <= b*3; col++) {
                if (row % 3 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else if (col % 3 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(".");
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        print(3, 1);
        print(4, 4);
    }
}
```